# how to add weight on stripchart's points in R?

Tags: r, graph, plot

I'm want to plot a stripchart with R.

```
x <- c(2, 8, 11, 19)
y <- c(12, 7, 8, 0)
stripchart(x)
```

[image]

**How to put weight contained in varaible y to be labels of variable x points ?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one of your "weights" is a zero maybe this isn't what you're looking for...

```
stripchart(x, cex=y)
```

gives different sized points depending on the magnitude of `y`.

Comment: I see that cex, modify the size of boxes, which other attributes of boxes can you also change ? color ? border ?

Comment: Another think is that weights can be very large up to 1000 that make boxes too big to feat in the picture, so what can we do else ? thanks for your time.

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin Use `log(y)` or `sqrt(y)` instead of `y`

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin Your initial comment above is best answered by the documentation, not StackOverflow. Try reading `?stripchart`, and follow the link provided next to the arguments `pch`, `col` and `cex`.